# Creating facet from a single data frame in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I create a plot with different facet based on each column but still the same value of `x` base on the row names.

Let's say I have a summary from `regsubsets()` but since it returns a list I have to make it as a data frame first (is there anyway I can use ggplot2 with list?).

```r
set.seed(1)
X = rnorm(100)
e = rnorm(100)
Y = 8 + 7*X + 2.5*X^2 - 9*X^3 + e
regfit.full = regsubsets(Y~poly(X,10,raw=T), data=data.all, nvmax=10)
(reg.summary = summary(regfit.full))

df = data.frame(reg.summary$cp, reg.summary$bic, reg.summary$adjr2)
```

```r
> names(df)
[1] "reg.summary.cp"    "reg.summary.bic"   "reg.summary.adjr2"

> dim(df)
[1] 10  3
```

Now the question is how can I make a facet for each features (i.e. `reg.summary.cp`, `reg.summary.bic`, `reg.summary.adjr2`) that will be the value on the y-axis and the value for the x-axis will be the row number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done by adding rownumbers and melting the dataframe using `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data.all = data.frame()

set.seed(1)

X = rnorm(100)
e = rnorm(100)
Y = 8 + 7 * X + 2.5 * X ^ 2 - 9 * X ^ 3 + e

regfit.full = regsubsets(Y ~ poly(X, 10, raw = T), data = data.all, nvmax = 10)
(reg.summary = summary(regfit.full))

df = data.frame(reg.summary$cp, reg.summary$bic, reg.summary$adjr2)
df$rownum <- 1:NROW(df)

molten_df <- melt(df, id.vars = "rownum")

ggplot(data = molten_df, aes(x = rownum, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable)
```

[image]

**EDIT:** maybe make the y-axes independet from one another by adding `scales = "free_y"`
So:

```
ggplot(data = molten_df, aes(x = rownum, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

**EDIT2:** a way to make the plot without melting `df`:

```
grid.arrange(
  ncol = 3,
  ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = rownum, y = reg.summary.cp)),
  ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = rownum, y = reg.summary.bic)),
  ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = rownum, y = reg.summary.adjr2))
)
```

Comment: do I really need to melt the `df`? and is it possible to make the scale of `y` for each facet base on each range in column not by overall data frame?